# R: identify duplicate rows and remove the old entry(By Date)

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe of the following form:

```
   ID    value    modified
1  AA    30       2016-11-03
2  AB    40       2016-11-04
3  AC    50       2016-11-05
4  AA    60       2016-11-06
5  AB    20       2016-11-07
```

I want to identify all the duplicate rows for ID column and remove rows which has comparatively old modification time. So the output will be:

```
   ID    value    modified
1  AC    50       2016-11-05
2  AA    60       2016-11-06
3  AB    20       2016-11-07
```

The code I am trying is as follows:

```
ID<-c('AA','AB','AD','AA','AB')
value<-c(30,40,50,60,20)
modified<-c('2016-11-03','2016-11-04','2016-11-05','2016-11-06','2016-11-07')
df<-data.frame(ID=ID,value=value,modified=modified)
df
  ID value   modified
1 AA    30 2016-11-03
2 AB    40 2016-11-04
3 AD    50 2016-11-05
4 AA    60 2016-11-06
5 AB    20 2016-11-07

df[!duplicated(df$ID),]
  ID value   modified
1 AA    30 2016-11-03
2 AB    40 2016-11-04
3 AD    50 2016-11-05
```

But this is not my desired output, how can I remove the old entries? Thank you in advance for any clue or hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `dplyr` package as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df %<>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(modified==max(modified))
```

And in case you want the result in a new variable

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(modified==max(modified))
```

Comment: Is this is complete code? I assume there are something wrong in the typo?

Comment: sorry added a missing bracket at the end

Comment: Yes, it works. Can you please tell what are %>% things?

Comment: sure, they are used for piping results to the next operation/function, you can read more about it here https://www.r-statistics.com/2014/08/simpler-r-coding-with-pipes-the-present-and-future-of-the-magrittr-package/

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the problem with base R by first sorting the data frame by date:

```
df <- df[order(df[["modified"]], decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

Then you can get the final result with your `!duplicated` solution:

```
df[!duplicated(df$ID), ]
```

Comment: `df[!duplicated(df$ID, fromLast=TRUE),]` - no need to do the sorting first in the current example.

Comment: @thelatemail, I love your comment, and I learned something new, but that only works if `modified` is in chronological order, which seems to be true in the example, but may not hold.