# Remove duplicate rows based on three columns

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data frame with prices of products on different dates. If there are same prices for a product on different dates, I would like to keep only the row with the most recent date.

Example of my data frame:

```
            Date           Price             Product
1         2019-08-28       10               product 1
2         2019-08-27       10               product 1
3         2019-08-28       15               product 2
4         2019-08-27       14               product 2
5         2019-08-23       15               product 2
6         2019-08-27       10               product 3
```

So I would like to get rid of row 2 and row 5 and only have:

```
            Date           Price             Product
1         2019-08-28       10               product 1
3         2019-08-28       15               product 2
4         2019-08-27       14               product 2
6         2019-08-27       10               product 3
```

Any suggestions? I could not find a question with a similar problem.

Comment: Have a look also at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40877964/10488504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order data by Date, then remove rows duplicated in the other two columns

```
df <- read.table(text = "          Date           Price             Product
1         2019-08-28       10               product1
                 2         2019-08-27       10               product1
                 3         2019-08-28       15               product2
                 4         2019-08-27       14               product2
                 5         2019-08-23       15               product2
                 6         2019-08-27       10               product3", 
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <- df[order(df[,1], decreasing = TRUE),]
df[!duplicated(df[,-1]),]

#        Date Price  Product
#1 2019-08-28    10 product1
#3 2019-08-28    15 product2
#4 2019-08-27    14 product2
#6 2019-08-27    10 product3
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort the dataframe first, then aggregate by selecting only the last row

```
df2=df[order(df$Date),]
aggregate(df2,list(df2$Price,df2$Product),tail,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)    
dat <- as.data.table(df) # using read.table('clipboard') for getting df
```

I set the latest date for the same price for each product as `new_date` - you can call it whatever you want:

```
> dat[, .(new_date = max(Date)), by = .(Product, Price)]
    Product Price   new_date
1: product1    10 2019-08-28
2: product2    15 2019-08-28
3: product2    14 2019-08-27
4: product3    10 2019-08-27
```

I find grouping by variables a bit more logical and easier to follow - this is done using the `by` argument of `data.table`. It also affords more flexibility in terms of getting the latest date (using `max`) or earliest date (using `min`) or any other combination therein. Of course, the `Date` column needs to be defined as in R date-time format.

for anyone trying to recreate this:

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18136, 18135, 18136, 18135, 
18131, 18135), class = "Date"), Price = c(10L, 10L, 15L, 14L, 
15L, 10L), Product = c("product1", "product1", "product2", "product2", 
"product2", "product3")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000001151ef0>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(desc(Date),Price, Product ) %>% 
  distinct(Price, Product, .keep_all = TRUE)
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

#         Date Price  Product
# 1 2019-08-28    10 product1
# 2 2019-08-28    15 product2
# 3 2019-08-27    10 product3
# 4 2019-08-27    14 product2
```

I'm explicit when using `arrange(desc(Date),Price, Product)` otherwise `arrange(desc(Date))` should suffice.